# Is dyn:evaluate() working inside <xsl:for-each>

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xalan

I'm trying to run many xpath queryes written in a configuration xml file on an input xml file:

```
<results>
<xsl:for-each select="$config_file/queries/*">

    <xsl:variable name="curr_item_name" select="name()"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="curr_xpath_query" select="."></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:element name="{$curr_item_name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate($curr_xpath_query)" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
</results>
```

I was expecting to have many xml element children of results (as many as queries' children) with the xpath evaluation result.

I get all tags named correctly but empty.

Cana anyone help me? As processor I'm using Xalan eclipse embedded processor (for now).

Thanks,
Laura

Comment: If I write an absolute xpath evaluation statement inside and outside the foreach loop the one outside the loop works fine, the one inside returns an empty result.

Comment: Please show us a source document, expected output, and actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So which node do you want to be the context node for your XPath evaluation? Currently it is any element you process with `$config_file/queries/*` and you use to provide the XPath expression. You probably want to store the XPath expression in a variable and then change the context with `for-each` or `apply-templates` to some other node you have not shown and which is not accessible if you haven't stored it previously in a variable. So let's assume you have a global variable

```
<xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="/"/>
```

and then you can use e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="path-exp" select="."/>
<xsl:for-each select="$main-doc//foo">
  <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate($path-exp)" />
</xsl:for-each>
```